# Java GUI to calibrate webcam based eyetracking using The Eye Tribe

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, eye-tracking

I'm doing a research using [The Eye Tribe Java SDK](https://github.com/EyeTribe/tet-java-client) to track eye gaze moving. I have build it  succesfully in IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle.

My first question is: can we make this work on webcam for testing?

If it work with webcam I want to run the "javafx-sample" to see the UI. But they only mentioned about C# based UI calibration (see http://dev.theeyetribe.com/csharp/#csharp_calibration).

Can anyone help me to make The Eye Tribe work in **Java UI** using webcam?